# Autofocus not working with AngularAgility

Tags: angularjs

Here is a plunker link of my code where it's shown that autofocus doesn't work 
http://jsfiddle.net/05hq7shr/118/

```
<div ng-form="exampleForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <input type="text" autofocus type="text" aa-field-group="myName" required />
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3">
            <button aa-submit-form="save()" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

using javascript you can focus the input on page load.

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("autoInput").focus();
};

<input type="text"  id="autoInput"  type="text" aa-field-group="myName" required />
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/05hq7shr/123/)

Comment: Why to use Javascript code just for `focus` when this can be achieved just by using HTML

Comment: we have to force focus on onload.

Comment: Actually I don't want to use JS script here. Need to properly find the cause why autofocus isn't working. @Sachila Ranawaka

Answer (score 1):

Strange , Don't know the reason but by removing

```
aa-field-group="myName"
```

from the input filed `focus` will work

Comment: But I need to use Angular Agility. That's why I have to use aa-filed-group and also need to make autofocus work.

Comment: Then you can explicitly call `focus` event on load of your component/page